# How do I use mongoexport and mongoimport?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to use mongoexport to store some documents and the mongoimport to put them on a remote server.  I've looked over the manual pages and looked around a little for some good examples, but I haven't seen anything specific enough yet.

I have a bunch of documents of type "Office" in my database that I want to export, but I don't have a clue how to use mongoexport properly.  Any tips or links to good examples are greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to export the whole database, or just specific documents?  There are some usage examples in the [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools); what additional information are you looking for?

Comment: Pointless question without information what "Office" means. As clear documented: mongoimport takes JSON/CSV data as import. Providing JSON/CSV as input is up to you and your application. What's your point?

Comment: You should post the code that you have tried, and the specific problem you are having. There are plenty of examples available in the docs and with a quick google to get you started.

Comment: I'll read around more and see what I come up with.

Answer (score 1):

to specify a collection, you use the -c switch

for example:

```
mongoexport -d databasename -c CollectionName -o outputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools

```
This utility takes a single file that contains 1 JSON/CSV/TSV string 
per line and inserts it. You have to specify a database and a collection.
```

Saying that you have no clue what it does is weird.

Comment: Specifying the collection is what I think I'm stuck on.